# sort version nicely with letters and numbers

Tags: python, sorting, alphanumeric

for some reason I cannot find this example 
I want to sort version numbers nicely.
for example
[v2,v10,v1]
to 
[v1,v2,v10]
I really only need the max but I can't find anything for that either.

Comment: Is `v2.1` valid? What about `v2.1.1`, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reinvent the `.whl`, you can use [`packaging.version`](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/version.html) which implements version parsing and ordering as specified in [PEP 440](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/).

To sort versions:

```
>>> from packaging.version import Version
>>> data = ['v2', 'v10', 'v1', 'v2.1', 'v2.1.1']
>>> sorted(data, key=Version)
['v1', 'v2', 'v2.1', 'v2.1.1', 'v10']
```

To find the latest version:

```
>>> max(data, key=Version)
'v10'
```